# Django - How to add an entry in Ascending order in the database efficiently?

Tags: django, algorithm

I am working on making an application in Django that can manage my GRE words and other details of each word. So whenever I add a new word to it that I have learnt, it should insert the word and its details in the database alphabetically. Also while retrieving, I want the details of the particular word I want to be extracted from the database.

Efficiency is the main issue.

Should I use SQLite? Should I use a file? Should I use a JSON object to store the data?
If using a file is the most efficient, what data structure should I implement?
Are there any functions in Django to efficiently do this?
Each word will have - meaning, sentence, picture, roots. How should I store all this information?

It's fine if the answer is not Django specific and talks about the algorithm or the type of database.

Comment: My first question would be why do you want to preserve the alphabetical order on insert? That means that you will automatically need to modify all the table records that follow that insert. You can retrieve the results sorted from the database. For django you can use order_by("field_name"). In terms or algorithm, such an approach is slow unless you use a specialised data structure. Take a look at what kind of data structure is used to create a database index.

Comment: In the search field, when someone types some letters, I want all the words starting with those letters to be displayed, like in all dictionaries. Sure I will read about it.

Comment: You should not care how the database stores the data; that is entirely its own concern. You should only care about how the data is given back to you, which you can control via ordering.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I digress a little, you should know and care about how indexes work (although for this user and application maybe not entirely necessary)

Comment: Okay thanks. Makes sense. Why I was concerned is because I wanted the autocomplete edit box, where all the words having the prefix as the typed text will be suggested. I'm still worried that even with ordering or by querying it with startswith as suggested in the answer, the process would be expensive. So I was wondering if I would instead have to implement a tree or some other structure to do it efficiently.

Comment: @The_coder expanded the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer from the data perspective since this is not totally related to django.

From your question it appears you have a fixed identifier for each "row": the word, which is a string, and a fixed set of attributes.

I would recommend using any enterprise level RDBMS. In the case of django, the most popular for the python ecosystem is PostgreSQL.

As for the ordering, just create the table with an index on the word name (this will be automatically done for you if you use the word as primary key), and retrieve your records using `order_by` in django.

Here's some info on [django field options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#field-options) (check `primary_key=True`)

And here's the info for the `order_by` [order_by method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)

Keep in mind you can also set the ordering in the `Meta` class of the model.

For your search case, you'll have to implement an endpoint that is capable of querying your database with `startswith`. You can check an example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#filtered-querysets-are-unique)

**Example model:**

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    roots = ...
    picture = ...
```

On your second question: "Is this costly?"
It really depends. With 4000 words I'll say: *NO*

You probably want to add a delay in the client to do the query anyways (for example "if the user has typed in and 500ms have passed w/o further input")
If I'm to give 1 good advice to any starting developer, it's **don't optimize prematurely**

Comment: At max, I will be working with 4000 words and a lot of information associated with each. So do you think, using startswith to query the words will be fast enough for my problem. It looks good and I'll read about it.

Comment: Yes, `4000` is a breeze for postgres

Comment: Also, if I want to make it efficient, should I implement something like a tree or a trie to only search in a particular branch? Because I suppose for the autocomplete textedit, with startswith, it will search all the words after every typed character. Also the ordering would not be needed now, right? Because I'll query it and ordering shouldn't affect the querying process?